# Handle jquery button click with multiple buttons with same class on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

So i have a function that i have build for some kind of repeatable text boxes that i can add and remove with click on a button.

But my problem is that now when i want to have 2 separated repeatable boxes on same page i can't separate click on button event.

This is output i use for repeatable options box.

```
$output .= '<div class="option">';
$output .= '<div class="vf-sortable-holder">';
$output .= '<div class="vf-sortable vf-repeat-text empty-sortable hidden"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>';
$output .= '<input id="' . esc_attr( $value['id'] ) . '" class="vf-input" data-rel="' . esc_attr( $option_name . '[' . $value['id'] . ']' ) . '" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $value['std'] ) . '" />';
$output .= '<a class="vf-delete-sortable button" href="#">'. __('Remove') .'</a>';
$output .= '</div>';

$output .= '</div>';
$output .= '<a class="vf-new-sortable button" href="#">Add new</a>';
$output .= '</div>';
```

And this is js function that i use to add a new text box

```
//Add new field for repeatable option
$('.vf-new-sortable').click( function(event) {

    //Get parent element
    var loop = $(this).closest('.option');

    // Count all repeat group div's
    var count = loop.find('.vf-sortable').not('.empty-sortable').length;

    //Add new slide
    var new_slide = loop.find('.empty-sortable').clone(true).removeClass('empty-sortable hidden').insertBefore('.empty-sortable');

    var input = new_slide.find('input');

    var input_name = input.attr('data-rel');
    input.attr('name', input_name + '[' + ( count ) + ']');
    return false;
});
```

What this should do is when page is loaded to have one vf-sortable div hidden and when i click on button it should clone it and make another vf-sortable field.

And this works. But problem is when i output 2 or more option div's with sortable boxes on button click it add new vf-sortable box on every option. how do i make event only to work on specific option div where add button is clicked?

Comment: change `.clone(true)` to `.clone(false)` to not clone the event handlers

Comment: I don't notice any difference, and looking into source with firebug everything looks the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change your .insertBefore() to insert before the actual loop.find('.empty-sortable') like this

```
$('.vf-new-sortable').click( function(event) {
    //Get parent element
    var loop = $(this).closest('.option');
    // Count all repeat group div's
    var count = loop.find('.vf-sortable').not('.empty-sortable').length;
    //Add new slide
    var emptysortable=loop.find('.empty-sortable');//get the element to clone
    var new_slide = emptysortable.clone(true).
                    removeClass('empty-sortable hidden').
                    insertBefore(emptysortable);//insert only in this .option
    var input = new_slide.find('input');
    var input_name = input.attr('data-rel');
    input.attr('name', input_name + '[' + ( count ) + ']');
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BCRt3/

Answer (score 0):

"how do i make event only to work on specific option div where add button is clicked?"

Perhaps something like adding an id to each option and then tying the button click to that specific option id.